# How can configure two tables for custom module?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, module, magento-1.8, adminhtml

I have a custom module. I am using this module to upload images through admin. I have 6 more form fields in my module. I am currently using one table to store values of these form fields. However as like in magento, i am planning to store image values in another table. My table structure is given below.

```
Table : Banner

        Fields :  banner_id( primary_key , int(11) ) 

                  banner_name( varchar (250) )

                  banner_count( small_int (6) )

                  status( small_int (6) )  

                  store_id( varchar (250) )   

Table : banner_images

        Fields : bi_id( primary_key , int (11) ) 

                 banner_id( int (11) ) //this should be the 'banner_id' of banner which holds this imge

                 bi_name( varchar (255) ) //stores image_name
```

My current edit file look like this:

```
<?php
class Karaokeshop_Banner_Block_Adminhtml_Banner_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_objectId = 'id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'banner';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_banner';
        $this->_updateButton('save', 'label', Mage::helper('banner')->__('Save Banner'));
        $this->_updateButton('delete', 'label', Mage::helper('banner')->__('Delete Banner'));


    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        if( Mage::registry('banner_data') && Mage::registry('banner_data')->getId() ) 
        {
            return Mage::helper('banner')->__("Edit Banner");
        } 
        else 
        {
            return Mage::helper('banner')->__('Add Banner');
        }
    }
}
```

My sql file look like this :

```
 ?php
      $installer = $this;
      $installer->startSetup();
      $installer->run("
          DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->getTable('banner')};
              CREATE TABLE {$this->getTable('banner')} (
                  `banner_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
                  `banner_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                  `banner_count` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
                  `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
                  `store_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                  `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
                   PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`)
             ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
          ");
     $installer->endSetup();
```

How can I achieve this? Please provide links, if there is any tutorials for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at these http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part6-series-models, http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part7-series-models-sql-operations, http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-blogs/admin-module-development/

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory under media or just inside your project folder. ( a place where you can access)
2. Save your images inside that directory.
3. In the database create a table which save the following attributes

> banner_id, path, banner_name, etc

Make sure when you loading images get the path from database table and load it.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have a directory in media folder. I can save image in that folder also. But i dont know how to store the image details in my second table

Comment: Store the `image path` and other relevant details. Use controller action and models to do this

Comment: that is what i am asking for. I configured my module with the first table only. How can configure my second table with my module and how can i does changes to my saveAction() according to it?

Comment: can we chat about this?

Comment: Try these links as well. http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.com/2011/04/upload-file-in-magento-how-to.html

Comment: This will also be helpfull http://www.rajujangid.com/file-upload-in-magento/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12263/discussion-between-su123-and-rajeevktomy)